# makefile: compile from different src dirs to separate obj dir

Tags: makefile

This is for a unit test makefile.  The directory structure, already established, is:

```
srca/ contains sources
srcb/ contains sources
test/ contains UT sources and Makefile
test/Debug is to contain objects
```

I can get it to work if I don't care that objects (.o, .gcda, etc.) are created in Test, with the following:

```
.PHONY = all build
all: build
vpath %.c ../srca ../srcb

SRC = \
    ../srca/a.c \
    ../srcb/b.c \
    test.c

OBJDIR=
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(notdir $(patsubst %.c, %.o , $(SRC))))

$(OBJ): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c

Debug/UnitTest.exe: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(OBJ) -o ./Debug/UnitTest.exe

build: Debug/UnitTest.exe
```

When I try to build objects into Debug by setting OBJDIR to Debug/, I get errors like the following:

```
test1.mk:16: target `Debug/a.o' doesn't match the target pattern
```

The line that sets OBJ was lifted from another stackoverflow post and I confess I don't follow it, but it works in the above case.  Also, the following line isn't needed when OBJDIR is empty:

```
$(OBJ): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
```

but if I omit it when OBJDIR is "Debug/", I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Debug/a.o', needed by `Debug/UnitTest.exe'.  Stop.
```

So, that rule helps when OBJDIR is not empty, but not quite enough.

Comment: How is that related to the C language or standard?

Comment: Are you or are you not putting a slash in `OBJDIR`?

Comment: @Beta: I've used the empty string and "./", both of which work, and "Debug/", which does not work (causes the error message about not matching the pattern.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `OBJDIR` (empty string), `OBJ` (`patsubst`) and your `%.o: %.c` rule are the main causes of your problem. In your example the value of `OBJ` is:

```
a.o b.o test.o
```

And your `%.o: %.c` rule expands as:

```
a.o b.o test.o: /%.o : %.c
```

Indeed, `a.o b.o test.o` do not match the `/%.o` pattern. You should replace your definitions of `OBJDIR` and `OBJ` by:

```
OBJDIR = .
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))))
```

Note that I also removed the spaces in the call of the `patsubst` function: with `make` spaces must be handled carefully. Avoid putting spaces where they are not needed, you will avoid subtle bugs, difficult to understand and fix, due to leading or trailing spaces in variable values.

If `OBJDIR` is set to something else than `.`, e.g. `Debug`, you will encounter another issue: implicit rules do not work like this and you will have to add an explicit recipe:

```
$(OBJ): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: It works when OBJDIR is blank (or "./"). It fails when OBJDIR is "Debug/".  Please explain why it fails in that case, which is the case I'm asking about.  Thanks for the point about spaces.

Comment: I do not understand how it could possibly work with a blank `OBJDIR` (for the reason I explained). There must be a subtle difference between what you show in your question and what you use. Or a make version that I do not know yet. In does not work with `OBJDIR = Debug/` because you do not tell make, for instance, how to build `Debug/a.o` from `../srca/a.c` (implicit rules do not cover this case). Add an explicit recipe: `gcc -c $< -o $@`.

Comment: Moreover, with `OBJDIR = Debug/` you have the same problem I ention in my answer: the rule expands as: `Debug/a.o Debug/b.o Debug/test.o: Debug//%.o : %.c` and there is no match because of the double slash.

Comment: You may wonder why it works with `OBJDIR = ./` while you should also have a matching error between `./a.o` and `.//%.o`. The answer is probably in the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Features): "Strip leading sequences of ‘./’ from file names, so that `./file` and `file` are considered to be the same file". I guess any `.///x` with any number of `/` is considered to be the same as `x`.

Comment: You're right that there was a difference: when it worked with OBJDIR blank, the "$(OBJ):" line was commented out.  Adding the explicit rule with the correct incantation works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the working makefile:

```
.PHONY = all build
all: build
vpath %.c ../srca ../srcb

SRC = \
    ../srca/a.c \
    ../srcb/b.c \
    test.c

OBJDIR=Debug/
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(notdir $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))))

$(OBJ): $(OBJDIR)%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

Debug/UnitTest.exe: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(OBJ) -o ./Debug/UnitTest.exe

build: Debug/UnitTest.exe
```